# How to change background color of cell in table using javascript if cell content match

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Powershell to pull data and generate an HTML file. I am adding an extra column to display if the expected State is Expected or Missing.

I am trying to update the Cell - Expected State-  background  (red if Missing, Green if Expected)

```js
var x = document.getElementById("tbody").getElementsByTagName("th");
x[0].innerHTML = "Missing";
x[0].style.backgroundColor = "Red";

var y = document.getElementById("tbody").getElementsByTagName("th");
y[0].innerHTML = "Missing";
y[0].style.backgroundColor = "Green";
```

```css
table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: .25em .5em;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font: .75em "Verdana";
}
```

```html
<table id="Table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>InstallState</th>
      <th>Expected State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Feature1</th>
      <th>Installed </th>
      <th>Expected</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Feature2</th>
      <th>Available </th>
      <th>Missing</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect to automatically color code the cell based on the value generated 1- Expected (green) 
2- Missing (Red)

Thank you,

Comment: You need to add `id='tbody'` id to the `tbody` element

Comment: Even with the correct `tbody` selector, `x` and `y` (and therefore `x[0]` and `y[0]`) are identical.

Comment: If you are already adding the "Expected" or "Missing" column using Powershell, why not have Powershell add that column with a class name so you can simply target that with CSS?

Comment: `document.getElementById("tbody")` cannot find an element with `id="tbody"` because you have none. That's why you get `"TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null",` error.

Comment: I was able to color code with the provided solution however when I apply it to all the document It doesn't seem to work.  
Here is the complete document: https://jsfiddle.net/facetubey/tapx05su/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use `document.querySelectorAll` for all th elements

1. Get all th elements by `document.querySelectorAll`
2. Loop all th elements by `for of`
3. Based on innerHTML content , update background color

```js
var th = document.querySelectorAll('th')
for (let cell of th) {
  if(cell.innerHTML === 'Expected'){
    cell.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
  }
  if(cell.innerHTML === 'Missing'){
    cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: .25em .5em;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font: .75em "Verdana";
}
```

```html
<table id="Table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>InstallState</th>
      <th>Expected State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Feature1</th>
      <th>Installed </th>
      <th>Expected</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Feature2</th>
      <th>Available </th>
      <th>Missing</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How can I apply it to the whole document ?  https://jsfiddle.net/facetubey/tapx05su/13/

Comment: As per question description , you should loop through tds right instead of th - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZdMyOe ,  document.querySelectorAll('td')

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this? Check if for every element that the inside HTML is equal to something. If it is then edit the CSS of that element

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("th"); // get all the elements for the th tag
Array.from(x).forEach((x) => { // convert the nodelist to array and forEach that array
  let theInnerHTML = x.innerHTML.toLowerCase().trim() // get the inner html for every array
  if (theInnerHTML == "expected") { // check if for every element that the inside html is equal to something. 
    x.style.backgroundColor = "Green"; // If it is then edit the css of that element 
  }
  if (theInnerHTML == "missing"){ // same here
   x.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: .25em .5em;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font: .75em "Verdana";
}
```

```html
<table id="Table">
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>InstallState</th>
      <th>Expected State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Feature1</th>
      <th>Installed </th>
      <th>Expected</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Feature2</th>
      <th>Available </th>
      <th>Missing</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```js
// iterate over the nodelist of all th elements in #Table
for (const th of Table.querySelectorAll('th')) {
  // depending on the lowercased, trimmed text in that th
  switch (th.textContent.toLowerCase().trim()) {
    // in case 'missing'
    case 'missing':
      th.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      break;
    // in case 'expected'
    case 'expected':
      th.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      break;
    // otherwise do nothing
    default:
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: .25em .5em;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font: .75em "Verdana";
}
```

```html
<table id="Table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>InstallState</th>
      <th>Expected State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Feature1</th>
      <th>Installed </th>
      <th>Expected</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Feature2</th>
      <th>Available </th>
      <th>Missing</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Because tbody is also a tag name you have to also getElementsByTagName with tbody.
But because this will give you an array, you have to also access that first element of that array like so:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("th");
```

---

Or you give that tbody an unique ID and access it by that:

```
<tbody id="myTableBody">
```

and then

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTableBody").getElementsByTagName("th");
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided answers on the correct Javascript solution. My question is: why do you want to use Javascript to fix a source document problem, when you can just generate the document correctly?

Since you're building the HTML with Powershell, I assume you're doing something like this *(I'm not a Powershell guy so this is probably not the correct syntax)*:

```
if (isExpected($feature)) {
    $html = $html + '<th>Expected</th>'
} else {
    $html = $html + '<th>Missing</th>'
}
```

If you want these specific `<th>`s to have a particular styling, just add a class:

```
if (isExpected($feature)) {
    $html = $html + '<th class="expected">Expected</th>'
} else {
    $html = $html + '<th class="missing">Missing</th>'
}
```

Then you can set the proper styling using CSS:

```
.expected {
    background-color: green;
}

.missing {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I tried before I went with JS. 
how can I embed HTML or CSS element in a PScustomObject without PS displaying it as Text?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not a Powershell guy so I have no idea. A quick Google search on how to dynamically generate a HTML document in PS tells me there are *a lot* of ways to do it so without seeing your actual PS script there's no way for me to tell you. But I *assume* you should be able to add the ` class="expected"` part to wherever you're currently adding the `<td>`, and you should be able to add the CSS to the document the same way you're currently adding Javascript code.